# C#: Can I code public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:MyClass AND implement an Interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, entity-framework-4

I see this:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:IComparable { }
```

and I have this:

```
public class ProductRepository : IRepository<Product> { }
```

How would you code something like this?

```
public class ProductRepository<T> where T : Product : IRepository<Product> {}
```

After all that, I thought I could simply make a single Repository class then inject the type to it, including the data context.  But, we pursue the simplest thing first right?  LOL

Update:

If I did this, how would I choose which Entity to use in the Entity Container (or Context)?  (Third line from the bottom starting with return _dc.Versions., which would somehow need switched to return _dc.T. )

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{   
    # region Constructor
    private AdSketchEntities _dc { get; set; } // Data Container (Data Context)
    public Repository() : this(new AdSketchEntities()) { }
    public Repository(AdSketchEntities myDC)
    {   this._dc = myDC; 
    }
    # endregion

    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        _dc.Versions.AddObject(entity);
        return _dc.Versions.Where(n => n.custid == entity.custid &&
                       n.versionid == entity.versionid).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify [multiple constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) like this:

```
public class ProductRepository<T>
    where T : Product, IRepository<Product>
{
}
```